# Code conflicts between Domain and Subdomain

Tags: mobile, dns, subdomain

I have a regular web site and a mobile site that both use App_Code folders. The problem is the sites share a lot of functionality. I have tried the following techniques

1. Referencing the Regular sites App_Code folder from the Subdomain.This doesn't work. I get a compile error
2. Duplicating the regular sites App_Code folder and using it in the sub domain. This leads to namespace conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing all the namespaces so they don't conflict...